# How do I calculate the following double integral and evaluate the limits of $\theta$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

Let R be a circular disc in $\Bbb R^2$  of a radius $a$ and center $(a,0)$. What is $$\int\int_R\ \frac{1}{x}dxdy$$

Used following equations:

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2\\
x = r \cos(\theta)\\
y = r \sin(\theta)$

The steps I followed :

$(x-a)^2 + (y)^2 = a^2\\
x^2 - 2xa + a^2 + y^2 = a^2\\
r^2 - 2(r\cos(\theta))a = 0 \\
 r = 0 , ~  r = 2a\cos(\theta)$

$$\begin{align*}&= \int _{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int _0^{2a\cos(\theta)}\frac{1}{r\cos(\theta)}~r~dr~d{\theta}\\&
= \int _{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}\int_0^{2a\cos(\theta)}dr~d\theta\\&
=\int _{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} 2a \space d\theta\\&= 2\pi a\end{align*}$$

I understand that for $r = 2a\cos(\theta),\theta$ goes between $0\to\pi/2$ for the upper part of the circle and between $\pi/2\to \pi$ for lower part of circle. As $r = -2a$, for $\theta = \pi $ so we discard $\pi$ and instead go between $0\to-\pi/2$ (For the lower part of the circle). Making the limits $ -\pi/2 \le\theta\le \pi/2$ . Needed a bit more elaboration on choice of $\theta$ and verification on my steps. If you guys could help out.

Comment: You forgot the $r$ in the second integral

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I think it got canceled in the first integral.

Comment: Sorry. Please ignore my earlier comment. Why does $\theta$ range from $\pi/2\to\pi$ for the lower part of the circle according to you? $\theta$ is measured in anti-clockwise manner from the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: As a sidenote, you may use "\" before function names like `\sin,\cos,\tan` etc. to prevent italicization, like so: `\cos` $\cos$ vs `cos` $cos$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri basically I thought that if for $\theta = 0, \space r = 2a$ and $\theta = \pi/2, \space r=  0$ (which covered upper part of the circle) Then from $ \pi/2 \to \pi$ (Covered lower part of the circle, except that at $\theta = \pi, \space r = -2a$ Which seemed incorrect) . So rather go clockwise for lower part of the circle. Yes I considered going in anticlockwise direction. Btw thanks for the response, edit and tips.

Comment: Can you tell me where you were measuring $\theta$ from for the upper part of the circle?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri upper part anticlockwise direction $0 \to \pi/2$

Comment: Okay, why did you change the reference for the lower part? If you are measuring in anti-clockwise manner from the positive $x$ axis, then for the lower part $\theta$ will range from $-\pi/2\to0$... note that $\cos\theta$ is negative when $\theta\in(\pi/2,\pi)$ so it is not *just* $\theta=\pi$ which is giving you a negative value of $r$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  oh right, yes cosine is negative in second quadrant makes sense. So, $\int_0^{\pi/2} + \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$ right?

Comment: Yeah, that is right.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thanks appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your work looks good.  But I don't get why you didn't just take $-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ to begin with.  I suppose it works with negative $r$ and angles above $\pi/2$, so you're not wrong, but I guess I just prefer to stick to positive $r$ where possible.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I will go through your solution

Comment: Hey, yeah it seems reasonable so stick with positive $r$. So $cos(\theta)$ is positive in first and fourth quadrant. So taking angle from $0  \to \pi/2$ and $-\pi/2 \to 0$ to keep $r$ positive. But I didn’t understand "take $\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$"

Comment: Whoops, lost the minus sign, fixed.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

This looks fine. However, you could just as easily have $\theta$ range from 0 to $\pi$, since for $\theta\in (\pi/2, \pi)$, the bound $r(\theta) = 2a\cos\theta$ will trace out the lower half of the circle, just using negative $r$ values and $\theta$ values that point in the opposite direction. In fact, technically speaking you could pick any interval of length $\pi$ for $\theta$: $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, $[-\pi/4,3\pi/4]$, $[0,\pi]$, $[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$, and $[11\pi, 12\pi]$ all work—you can quickly observe that all of these intervals for $\theta$ will yield the same result since the integrand for the integral with respect to $\theta$ ends up not depending on $\theta$. If you want to be convinced further, you could also hop onto your online graphing calculator of choice and graph your $r(\theta)$ function for those various intervals to observe that, for each one, you get the same circle.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Different interval gave a new perspective to the Question. Understandable

Answer (score 1):

Note that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\int_{\begin{subarray}{c}B(0,r_{2})\setminus B(0,r_{1})\\\theta\in(\theta_{1},\theta_{2})\end{subarray}}\frac{1}{x}dxdy
&=&
\int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}\int_{r_{1}}^{r_{2}} \frac{1}{r\cos(\theta)} rdrd\theta\\
&=&    \int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}\int_{r_{1}}^{r_{2}} \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)} drd\theta\\
&=&    \int_{\theta_{1}}^{\theta_{2}}\sec{\theta}d\theta\cdot(r_{2}-r_{1})
\end{eqnarray*}

is a general case for $[r_{1},r_{2}]\times[\theta_{1},\theta_{2}]\subseteq[0,+\infty)\times[0,2\pi)$ (in polars coordinates).

Comment: This works if the region to be integrated over was a "rectangle" equivalent in polar, which would be a slice of an annulus subtended by a central angle.  In this situation, the $r$'s are functions of $\theta$.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I will go through it.

Comment: Oh yes, quite right, it is for a region as it says @RobertTheTutor